# How to show an alert on the success url

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I want to display a message that form has been successfully submitted when the user gets redirected to success url but I cannot find a solution to do it. Please help.Thanks!

views

```
class FeedbackCreate(CreateView):
    model = Feedback
    form_class = FeedbackForm
    template_name = 'feedback_form.html'
    success_url = '/qworky/dash/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.premises =    Premises.objects.get(userprofile__user=self.request.user)
         self.object.client = UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
         return super(FeedbackCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Did u try django messages https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/messages/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [**`SuccessMessageMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#django.contrib.messages.views.SuccessMessageMixin):

```
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin

class FeedbackCreate(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Feedback
    form_class = FeedbackForm
    template_name = 'feedback_form.html'
    success_url = '/qworky/dash/'
    success_message = 'Well done! We saved your feedback!'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.premises =    Premises.objects.get(userprofile__user=self.request.user)
        self.object.client = UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        return super(FeedbackCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

In your templates you can render such messages, as is discussed in the [documentation on the *messages framework*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#displaying-messages). It might be better to do the rendering on your base template, such that on all pages, the messages can be delivered.